# What does Raw Defiance mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I looked up about the word "Raw" and found it has bunch of different meanings, one of them being 'A Natural, uncontrolled quality'

And, the other day, I heard someone say, in a bit of an apprehensive tone, "He is of raw defiance".

I couldn't seem to reproduce its usage in this context, what other sorts of qualities can I pair with 'Raw' and do the qualities always need to be indicative of strength and superiority?

How else can it be used, it'd be great to see a couple of examples.

Answer (score 1):

By *Natural* they mean unrefined and in the case of *Raw defiance* likely impolite; including rough edges. *Raw talent* would be natural, inborn talent; not learned from teachers or coaches.

Raw can also be used pejoratively to indicate low quality of talent or skill; rough, amateurish. New soldiers, just out of basic training are referred to as raw or green, as in unseasoned, in that they are brand new and without the needed experience that testing in combat will hopefully bring them.